# I've tried below on my pc and it works perfectly but on pyschools site still appears "float division by zero " . Why ??:

Tags: python

Please find the description of the problem in the link below :
[EOF while parsing at the end of my code ;estimatePi() problem from pyschools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743779/eof-while-parsing-at-the-end-of-my-code-estimatepi-problem-from-pyschools)

Write a function estimatePi() to estimate and return the value of pi based on the formula found by an Indian Mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan. It should use a while loop to compute the terms of the summation until the last item is smaller than 1e -15. The formula for calculating distance is given below:

[image]

```
import math
def estimatePi():
  k=0
  x=0  
  sum1=0  
  def factorial(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * factorial(n-1) 
  while x<1/1000000000000000 :
      x=(factorial((4*k))*(1103+26390*k))/(factorial(k)**4*396**(4*k))
      sum1+=x
      k+=1
  return 9801/(2*math.sqrt(2)*sum1  )
print(estimatePi())
```

Comment: Python2 `/` integer division against Python3 `/` true division? Check your python versions on both systems... In Python2 `1/100000000000` is `0`.

Comment: simplified test for pyschool: if `print "hello world"` works, its a python 2 (print == not a function)

Comment: If it's a python 2 environment you could just replace your while with `while x < 1./1000000000000000` to make the division with a float number.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- In Python2, `1/1000000000000000` is exactly `0` because of integer division, so the while loop is never run, `sum1` stays at `0` and `9801/(2*math.sqrt(2)*sum1)` fails with division by 0. You could replace it with `1E-15`.
- You start with `x = 0` but as soon as you calculate `x`, it becomes larger than `1E-15` so the `while` loop runs only once. You could set `x` to `1` and run the `while` loop as long as `x` is **larger** than `1E-15`
- `pi` is defined in `math` so you probably shouldn't import `math`. You could simply use `**0.5` instead of `sqrt`.
- `(factorial((4*k))*(1103+26390*k))/(factorial(k)**4*396**(4*k))` returns `0` in Python2 for any `k` larger than 1. You should use float division instead.

Here's a modified code which should work fine with Python2 and Python3:

```
def estimatePi():
    k = 0
    x = 1
    sum1 = 0

    def factorial(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * factorial(n-1)
    while x > 1E-15:
        x = float(factorial(4*k)*(1103+26390*k)) / (factorial(k)**4*396**(4*k))
        sum1 += x
        k += 1
    return 9801/(2*2**0.5*sum1)


print(estimatePi())
# 3.141592653589793 in Python3
# 3.14159265359 in Python2
```